# Definite integral of a function containing max()

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to determine the constant c so that this definite integral evaluates to 1. I have no information about the behaviour of this function in different intervals (e.g. which term inside max() is greater or smaller than the other in different intervals - is not known). |x| is absolute function.

[image: integral_function]

Comment: I can't see the function. Also, if you cannot determine which of the two components in max is greater, how can you even compute the integrand unless there is some special structure to the integrand that allows you to ignore this.

Comment: Can you see the function now. Sorry, I shared it using some other service but the link didn't work here.

Comment: Hint: $\text{max}{(x,y)}=\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac12|x-y|$.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks but the question again is about splitting the intervals for the second term in your hint. We don't know when x>y or y>x.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^2$ can be broken up into different regions to make this problem easier.  Let's find the first region together.

Let's first assume $x>a$ and $y>b$ (and that $K_1,K_2>0$.  Consider $\frac{x-a}{K_1}$ and $\frac{y-b}{K_2}$.  When is $\frac{x-a}{K_1}>\frac{y-b}{K_2}$.
$$\frac{x-a}{K_1}>\frac{y-b}{K_2} \Rightarrow x-a > \frac{y-b}{K_2}K_1=\frac{y-b}{C}$$ where $C=\frac{K_2}{K_1}$.  Then $x>\frac{1}{C}y-\frac{b}{C}+a$.  Thus, we've found our first region.

Go about breaking up $\mathbb{R}^2$ into the relevant regions, and this will correspond to breaking up the double integration into a sum of integrations of simple polynomial functions.

Comment: hi, we can't put the limits of x as a function of y, right ?

Comment: I think you can actually.  Your outer integral would go from 0 to infinity, and your inner integral would go from the line to infinity.

Comment: Also, Happy New Years!  :)

Comment: Hi, the problem would then reduce to finding elementary integration of e^(-x^2) and the limits are not -inf to +inf anymore so we can't use the gaussian integral here.